# Usage of constructor in Entity Framework model class

Tags: entity-framework

Can someone help me understand what purpose the Department constructor has in the class below, taken from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx

```
public class Department 
{ 
    public Department() 
    { 
        this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>(); 
    } 
    // Primary key 
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public decimal Budget { get; set; } 
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; } 
    public int? Administrator { get; set; } 

    // Navigation property 
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; private set; } 
}
```

Versus this example where they don't use a constructor, taken from http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

```
 public class Department
   {
      public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

      [StringLength(50, MinimumLength=3)]
      public string Name { get; set; }

      [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
      [Column(TypeName = "money")]
      public decimal Budget { get; set; }

      [DataType(DataType.Date)]
      [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
      [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
      public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

      public int? InstructorID { get; set; }

      public virtual Instructor Administrator { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
   }
```

The Course class is identical in both.

Is this just a case of the latter being EF6 and the former deprecated?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about the initialization of the `Courses` property?

Comment: Correct, I see two different tutorials for essentially the same example. One has the initialization, and one doesn't. Would like to understand the purpose of it, and if thats required in EF6 because its not present in the EF6 tutorial.       

    `public Department() 
    { 
        this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>(); 
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just lets `Courses` always be initialized.

Imagine this:

```
var d = new Department();
d.Courses.Add(new Course());
```

In the first example you gave, the one with the constructor, it's fine. For the second example, this will throw a `NullReferenceException` as the Courses object hasn't been initialized.